# Coverting from RawValues to Values for gyro in wiimotion plus - Wiimotelib 1.8 beta

Tags: c#, wii, wiimote

Using:

```
Wiimote.WiimoteState.MotionPlusState.RawValues;
```

I can retrive the raw values of the gyroscope from the WiiMotion plus, However, these values for rotational acceleration are completely arbitrary and are of little use to me as they stand.

I believe that:

```
Wiimote.WiimoteState.MotionPlusState.Values;
```

will give me the data in g's as is the case with the accelerometer data from the wiimote in the Wiimote library. Unfortunately, when I use this, I get no data, x, y and z are all zero.

Can someone either explain how to convert the raw values into meaningful g's or shed some light as to why I cant retrive the information normally.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using WiimoteLib, its because its a beta release; the conversion from RawValues to Values are still stub methods. I used this normalization technique:
   1.   Calibrate the Motionplus (i.e. Find the raw value that corresponds to zero; I do this by holding it stationary for a point of time)
   2.   For every subsequent raw value read, I subtract the zero value from it to get the "relative" raw value.
   3.   Then, I scale this value using http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote/Extension_Controllers (checking for yaw_fast, pitch_fast etc.), where the numerical values are computed using the measure (raw value of 8192 corresponds to 595 deg/s)
   4.   I sum up all these values over time (discrete integration) to get the angle of the wiimote wrt initial orientation.

When I tested this by turning the wiimote in the yaw direction 90 degrees and back, I did get a nice corresponding graph.But, my values are not to scale and I have no idea how to convert it without knowing the maximum value (i.e. the value that 360 degrees corresponds to) Maybe I should run some more tests on that,

but if anyone's got any other ideas, I'm waiting too...